# Problema con try y except

Tags: python-3.x

En el script que muestro a continuación, cuando respondo al input con número mayor de 3, ¿Por qué no me devuelve la sentencia indicada en 'except'?. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
lista = ["tenis", "futbol", "balón mano", "balón cesto"]

for counter, value in enumerate (lista, 0):
    print (counter, value)
    
try:
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione un valor: "))
    seleccion = lista[opcion]

except ValueError as err:
    print('Error, introduzca un numero valido')
    quit()
```

Me devuelve.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11552/3515813278.py in <module>
      6 try:
      7     opcion = int(input("Seleccione un valor: "))
----> 8     seleccion = lista[opcion]
      9 
     10 except ValueError as err:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos errores distintos.

Tu `except` sólo opera si se produce un `ValueError`. Lo que tienes es un `IndexError`, que no está cubierto por ningun `except`.

Agrega un `except` por excepción que quieres manejar

#### Demo

```
lista = ["tenis", "futbol", "balón mano", "balón cesto"]

for counter, value in enumerate(lista, 0):
    print(counter, value)

try:
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione un valor: "))
    seleccion = lista[opcion]

except ValueError as err:
    print('Error, introduzca un numero valido')
    quit()
except IndexError as err:
    print('Error, opción fuera de rango')
```

produce:

```
1 futbol
2 balón mano
3 balón cesto
Seleccione un valor: 4
Error, los valores válidos son 0, 1, 2, 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```